# Search filter triggered & sort by custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, filters, search, conditional-content

I am using a plugin ([Relevanssi](http://wordpress.org/plugins/relevanssi/)) and a custom function to sort the search results by custom post types (see below).  *This is working great*.

```
add_filter('relevanssi_hits_filter', 'separate_result_types');
function separate_result_types($hits) {
    $types = array();
 
    // Split the post types in array $types
    if (!empty($hits)) {
        foreach ($hits[0] as $hit) {
            if (!is_array($types[$hit->post_type])) $types[$hit->post_type] = array();                        
            array_push($types[$hit->post_type], $hit);
        }
    }
 
    // Merge back to $hits in the desired order
    $hits[0] = array_merge((array)$types['cats'], (array)$types['dogs'], (array)$types['horses']);
   return $hits;
    
}
```

The problem arises when I want to display search results on a per-type basis.  For example, when on the "Search Pets" page (which is a page template, search-pets.php) I want to display only search results for the above CPTs.  When on the "Blog" page (standard WP posts), I want to display only blog posts, and if on a non custom CPT page, display page results.  I thought that by adding an if/else statement (see below) that would work.

```
add_filter('relevanssi_hits_filter', 'separate_result_types');
function separate_result_types($hits) {
    $types = array();
 
    // Split the post types in array $types
    if (!empty($hits)) {
        foreach ($hits[0] as $hit) {
            if (!is_array($types[$hit->post_type])) $types[$hit->post_type] = array();                        
            array_push($types[$hit->post_type], $hit);
        }
    }
 
    // If post type = dogs, cats, horses
    if (in_array( get_post_type(), array('dogs','cats','horses'))){
    // Merge back to $hits in the desired order
    $hits[0] = array_merge((array)$types['dogs'], (array)$types['cats'], (array)$types['horses']);
   // return $hits;
    
    } else {
    
     // If post type = posts, page
    if (in_array( get_post_type(), array('post','page'))){
    // Merge back to $hits in the desired order
    $hits[0] = array_merge((array)$types['post'], (array)$types['page']);
    //return $hits;

    }}
    return $hits;
}
```

But it only seems to return the top filter results.  Any idea where I'm going wrong, or if my logic will even work?  Very much a PHP noob.  Thanks!

Ramsey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That doesn't appear to be a WordPress post Loop so you will need to pass the post ID or the post object to `get_post_type`. I don't know much about Relevansi but in your code above, that looks like `$hit` might be that object.

However, I don't think that is what you want. I may be reading you wrong but it sounds like you want "if on a category archive page" and not "if this post is a". In that case the function you need are these-- [the "Conditional Tags"](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags).

So this...

```
// If post type = dogs, cats, horses
if (in_array( get_post_type(), array('dogs','cats','horses'))){
  // ...
}
```

Becomes ([`using is_post_type_archive`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_post_type_archive))...

```
// If post type = dogs, cats, horses
if (is_post_type_archive('dogs')
    || is_post_type_archive('cats')
    || is_post_type_archive('horses')
){
   // ...
}
```